# How to merge methods with the same body but different signatures together?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

This is a refactoring question.

How to merge all these Check() methods into one single Generic Check() method since their method bodies are the same?

```
ppublic class ChangeDetector : IChangeDetector
{
    private readonly IEqualityHelper _equalityHelper;

    public ChangeDetector(IEqualityHelper equalityHelper)
    {
        _equalityHelper = equalityHelper;
    }

    public bool ChangeDetected { get; private set; }

    public void Check<T>(IList<T> existingList, IList<T> newList) where T : IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T>, new ()
    {
        if (!this._equalityHelper.Equals(existingList, newList))
        {
            NotifyChange();
        }
    }

    public void CheckEntities<T>(IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T> existingObj, IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T> newObj) where T : IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T>, new()
    {
        if (!this._equalityHelper.Equals(existingObj, newObj))
        {
            NotifyChange();
        }
    }

    public void Check(string existing, string newVal)
    {
        if (!this._equalityHelper.Equals(existing, newVal))
        {
            NotifyChange();
        }
    }

    public void Check<T>(T existing, T newVal) where T : struct 
    {
        if (!this._equalityHelper.Equals(existing, newVal))
        {
            NotifyChange();
        }
    }

    public void Check<T>(T? existing, T? newVal) where T : struct 
    {
        if (!this._equalityHelper.Equals(existing, newVal))
        {
            NotifyChange();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyChange()
    {
        ChangeDetected = true;
    }
}
```

My EqualityHelper class members have different body though which is fine:

```
public class EqualityHelper : IEqualityHelper
    {
        public bool Equals<T>(IList<T> existingList, IList<T> newList) where T : IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T>, new()
        {
            if (existingList == null || existingList.Count == 0)
            {
                if (newList != null && newList.Count > 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (newList == null
                    || existingList.Count != newList.Count
                    || newList.Any(newListItem => existingList.Any(existingListItem => existingListItem.Id == newListItem.Id)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public bool Equals<T>(IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T> existingObj, IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T> newObj) where T : IdentifiedActiveRecordBase<T>, new()
        {
            if (existingObj == null)
            {
                if (newObj != null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (newObj == null || existingObj.Id != newObj.Id)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public bool Equals(string existing, string newVal)
        {
            return string.Equals(existing, newVal);
        }

        public bool Equals<T>(T existing, T newVal) where T : struct
        {
            return !existing.Equals(newVal);
        }

        public bool Equals<T>(T? existing, T? newVal) where T : struct
        {
            if ((existing.HasValue && !newVal.HasValue)
                || (!existing.HasValue && newVal.HasValue)
                || existing.Equals(newVal))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that even possible?  I mean, I don't really know, you seem like you have much more experience than I do, but my first guess is that the bodies aren't really the same?  The signature inside the bodies would all be different because the variable they're working with, 'existing' doesn't have the same signature, itself?  Maybe just declare it dynamic?  But if you declare it dynamic you take a performance hit, if I'm not mistaken, because that's late-binding.

Comment: Not sure, maybe not possible. I just see duplicated body that could potentially be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the method bodies are looking similar doesn't mean the method signatures can be merged. Each of your five `Handle` methods calls five different `Equals`-methods, so unless you can merge the five Equals methods, you can't merge the Handle methods. You can't do that of course because the Equals method implementations are different. Remember that which of the Equals-method are to be called is decided compile-time, not runtime.

**Edit:** What you *could* do is change the signature of both `Handle/Check` and `Equals` to `Check(object existing, object equals)` and `Equals(object existing, object equals)`. Then in the `Equals`-method perform a runtime type-check which results in a switch-case to the five Equals-method you already have with the help of type casting. This would make the implementation slower and only arguably more maintainable. I'm not sure I would go down that route.

Comment: I can not definitely merge all the Equals methods since their body is different.

Comment: And so are the five Handle-methods under the hood. They compile to five different method calls.

Answer (score 1):

The method bodies aren't really the same, since they're all calling different `Equals()` methods. What you're intending to do would (if I understand the question correctly) finish up with one `Handle<T>()` method where `T` could be any type. Thinking about what you're trying to express in the code, it seems fair that if you have one `Handle<T>()` method, that ought to be able to call one `Equals<T>()` method. That way, you can implement your handling logic once (and potentially this becomes more complex later but you only need to write it once) and you delegate the tricky business of comparing objects to your equality comparer class.

Comment: Yes, that's the question.

Comment: You can't get away with one Handle<T> when not all Handle-methods are generic and not all generic methods have the same constraints.